# What should I return in an https callable function if it doesn't expect to return nothing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have implemented a HTTPs (onCall) function that throws some errors to the client or return *true* if the work is successfully completed. The problem is that I don't see why to return true (because when I throw the errors I don't return *false*).

As HTTP protocol requires to return a response to the client to finish a request, what should I return to the client? I am thinking to remove the errors I throw and return a classic HTTP reponse (status code, body, ...).

Any ideas? Here is what I am doing:

```
exports.function = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

        // Lazy initialization of the Admin SDK
        if (!is_function_initialized) {
          // ... stuff
          is_uploadImage_initialized = true;
        }
    
        // ... asynchronous stuff
    
        // When all promises has been resolved...
        // If work completed successfully
        return true;
    
       /*
         Is it correct instead ???
         return {code: "200 OK", date: date, body: message };
       */
    
    
       // Else, if errors
       throw new Error("Please, try again later.");
    
       /*
         Is it correct instead ???
         return {code: "418 I'm a teapot", date: date, body: message };
       */

   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

> To use HTTPS Callable Functions you must use the client SDK for your
> platform together with the `functions.https` backend API (or implement
> the [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference))

which means that **you must follow the protocol in any case**, since the Client SDKs do implement the protocol.

#### So let's look at what says the protocol about the response to be sent to the client (i.e. the caller or consumer):

The protocol specifies the format of the [Response Body](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#response_body) as follows:

> The response from a client endpoint **is always a JSON object**. At a
> minimum it contains either `data` or `error`, along with any optional
> fields. If the response is not a JSON object, or does not contain data
> or error, the client SDK should treat the request as failed with
> Google error code INTERNAL .
>
> `error` - ....
>
> `data` - The value returned by the function. **This can be any valid JSON value**. The firebase-functions SDK automatically encodes the value
> returned by the user into this JSON format. The client SDKs
> automatically decode these params into native types according to the
> serialization format described below.
>
> If other fields are present, they should be ignored.

So, to answer to your question "what should I return to the client?", you should return **data that can be JSON encoded**. See also this [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#response_to_encode) of the protocol doc.

---

For example, as detailed in the doc, in a Callable Cloud you can do

```
return {
  firstNumber: firstNumber,
  secondNumber: secondNumber,
  operator: '+',
  operationResult: firstNumber + secondNumber,
};
//Excerpt of the doc
```

or, you can do

```
return {result: "success"}
```

In your specific case ("What should I return in an https callable function if it doesn't expect to return nothing") you could very well return the following, as you mentioned in your question:

```
const date = new Date();
const message = "the message";

return { code: "200 OK", date: date, body: message };
```

But you could also do `return true;` or `return null;`... It's somehow up to you to decide what makes sense in your context.

---

Note that in the case you return `{ code: "200 OK", date: date, body: message }` the value of `code` will not be considered, by the client, as an HTTP Response code, since this JSON object is injected in the Response body.